# Subclassing collections namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

Python's namedtuple can be really useful as a lightweight, immutable data class. I like using them for bookkeeping parameters rather than dictionaries. When some more functionality is desired, such as a simple docstring or default values, you can easily refactor the namedtuple to a class. However, I've seen classes that inherit from namedtuple. What functionality are they gaining, and what performance are they losing? For example, I would implement this as

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Pokemon(namedtuple('Pokemon', 'name type level')):
    """
    Attributes
    ----------
    name : str
        What do you call your Pokemon?
    type : str
        grass, rock, electric, etc.
    level : int
        Experience level [0, 100]
    """
     __slots__ = ()
```

For the sole purpose of being able to document the attrs cleanly, and `__slots__` is used to prevent the creation of a `__dict__` (keeping the lightweight nature of namedtuples).

Is there a better recommendation of a lightweight data class for documenting parameters? Note I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: See also this post on alternative data containers https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784683/4531270, i.e. `NamedTuple` and dataclasses.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**NEW UPDATE:**

In python 3.6+, you can use the new typed syntax and create a `typing.NamedTuple`. The new syntax supports most of the usual python class creation features (docstrings, default arguments, methods, etc etc are available as of 3.6.1; however multiple inheritance is not supported):

```
import typing

class Pokemon(typing.NamedTuple):
    """
    Attributes
    ----------
    name : str
        What do you call your Pokemon?
    type : str
        grass, rock, electric, etc.
    level : int
        Experience level [0, 100]
    """
    name: str
    type: str
    level: int = 0 # 3.6.1 required for default args

    def method(self):
        # method work
```

The class objects created by this version are mostly equivalent to the original `collections.namedtuple`, [except for a few details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple).

You can also use the same syntax as the old named tuple:

```
Pokemon = typing.NamedTuple('Pokemon', [('name', str), ('type', str), ('level', int)])
```

**Original Answer**

---

Short answer: [no, unless you are using Python < 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606436/adding-docstrings-to-namedtuples)

The [P3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) seem to imply pretty clearly that unless you need to add calculated fields (i.e., descriptors), subclassing `namedtuple` is not considered the canonical approach. This is because you can update the docstrings directly (they are now writable as of 3.5!).

> Subclassing is not useful for adding new, stored fields. Instead, simply create a new named tuple type from the `_fields` attribute...
>
> Docstrings can be customized by making direct assignments to the `__doc__` fields...

UPDATE:

There are now a couple other compelling possibilities for lightweight data classes in the latest versions of Python.

One is [`types.SimpleNamespace` (Python 3.3 and later)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#additional-utility-classes-and-functions). It is not structured like `namedtuple`, but structure isn't always necessary.

One thing to note about `SimpleNamespace`: by default it is required to explicitly designate the field names when instantiating the class. This can be got around fairly easily, though, with a call to `super().__init__`:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Pokemon(SimpleNamespace):
    """
    Attributes
    ----------
    name : str
        What do you call your Pokemon?
    type : str
        grass, rock, electric, etc.
    level : int
        Experience level [0, 100]
    """
    __slots__ = ("name", "type", "level")
    # note that use of __init__ is optional
    def __init__(self, name, type, level):
        super().__init__(name=name, type=type, level=level)
```

Another intriguing option- [which is available as of Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370a4/) - is [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (see also [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pokemon:
    __slots__ = ("name", "type", "level")
    name: str  # What do you call your Pokemon?
    type: str  # grass, rock, electric, etc.
    level: int = 0  # Experience level [0, 100]
```

Note that both of these suggestions are mutable by default, and that `__slots__` is not required for either one.

Comment: When subclassing any class alongside NamedTuple, the other classes are all ignored. So in the first example `Pokemon` cannot use method declared inside `MyMixin`

you can see my question here for further info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707607/weird-mro-result-when-inheriting-directly-from-typing-namedtuple

Comment: Where is `MyMixin` defined?

Comment: @Stevoisiak it is just an optional placeholder. I included it to demonstrate the order of inheritance you would (usually?) use when mixing in other parent class behavior.

Comment: To reiterate what @WayneChang said, this answer is incorrect; `class Pokemon(MyMixin, typing.NamedTuple)` does not work.  In newer versions of Python, this results in `TypeError: can only inherit from a NamedTuple type and Generic`.

Comment: @WayneChang I did not realize it at the time but you were correct. I removed `MyMixin` from the example.