# Python : How do I create an object where the superclass is both blank and inherits from typing.NamedTuple?

Tags: python, types, namedtuple, python-typing

I would like to set up an abstraction where I would like to only allow the sub datatypes of `Foo` to be passed in parts of my application. All of these really are typed `NamedTuples`, as they carry no functionality. This leads me to have `Foo` inherit from `typing.NamedTuple`, and add no additional functionality to `Foo`. My issue is when instantiating subtypes of `Foo`, I am greeted with an error.

Consider the following snippet

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Foo(NamedTuple):
    pass


class Bar(Foo):
    a: int
    b: str
        
        
class Baz(Foo):
    one_thing: float
    another_thing: float

bar = Bar(4, "sdlfkjsdfkj")
print(bar)
```

The output of the snippet will be the following error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b0f9b9293905> in <module>
     15     another_thing: float
     16 
---> 17 bar = Bar(4, "sdlfkjsdfkj")
     18 print(bar)

TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

However if I let `Bar` inherit directly from `typing.NamedTuple` then I am able to get the following snippet to function properly

```
class Bar(NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: str
        
bar = Bar(4, "sdlfkjsdfkj")
print(bar)
```

```
>>> Bar(a=4, b='sdlfkjsdfkj')
```

Does this mean that for each data class definition (such as `Bar` or `Baz`) I have to inherit from `typing.NamedTuple`? Why can I not factor that out to a top level class?

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You cannot inherit from a class that inherits from `NamedTuple`.  I also wished it were otherwise.  Because a `Named Tuple` is at heart just a tuple, it's a bit unclear what the semantics of subclassing it would mean.

Comment: I'm not really sure what overall problem you're trying to solve this way, but maybe dataclasses could help?

Comment: Because `typing.NamedTuple` is not a true class. Note, `isinstance(typing.NamedTuple, Foo())` is *false*. Basically, `NamedTuple` uses metaclass magic to generate a class that inherits from *tuple*. It's not very nice, but "practicality beats purity". See [this answer I wrote to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707607/weird-mro-result-when-inheriting-directly-from-typing-namedtuple/60883973#60883973)

Comment: Note that logically, ``NamedTuple`` subtypes may not have different attributes. A (named) tuple allows direct (attribute) item access *and* (attribute) item unpacking, meaning that both the count and order of attributes is guaranteed. A subclass adding attributes fails that.