# How to add recursive `.json()` method to subclass of **NamedTuple**

Tags: python, python-typing

I currently have a couple of classes following the pattern described in the code below:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Data(NamedTuple):
   name: str,
   value: float
   
   def json(self):
       return {'name': self.name, 'value': self.value}
```

Instead of defining a `json` method in every new class that I create, I would like to extend `typing.NamedTuple`, so that I can extend from my new class without having to define the json method in the subclasses.  `typing.NamedTuple` already provides the `_asdict` method, but this method is not sufficient because it is not recursive (Nested namedtuples will not be converted to dict objects).

I have tried to attempt this in the code below:

```
class JsonNamedTuple(NamedTuple):
    def json(self):
        # some slightly complex recursive code here

class Data(JsonNamedTuple):
    name: str,
    value: float

a = Data('asdf', 0.5)
```

I get this error:
`TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

Is there a way to extend `typing.NamedTuple` without getting this error?

Comment: On a terminological note, `json` doesn't return JSON; it returns a `dict`.

Comment: Named tuples already have a method that returns such a dict: `Data('asdf', 0.5)._asdict()`.

Comment: Because of how `NamedTuple` works, I think you have to provide the fields immediately; you cannot "suspect" the creation of the new type until a subclass provides fields.

Comment: @chepner `_asdict()` helps, but is not recursive. If I have a `NamedTuple` nested inside a `NamedTuple`, when calling `_asdict()` on the outer object will still return a `NamedTuple` in the inner one.

Comment: That's a requirement that should be added to the question.

Comment: (Oh, and "suspend", not "suspect".)

Comment: Note, typing.NamedTuple isn't a real class. So extending it isn't going to work. Note, `isinstance(Data('foo', 4.24), NamedTuple)` is False. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707607/weird-mro-result-when-inheriting-directly-from-typing-namedtuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't actually extend `typing.NamedTuple`.

You can however create a class decorator like so:

```
import typing

class _JsonMixin:
    def json(self):
        # some slightly complex recursive code here
        return {'name': self.name, 'value': self.value}

def jsonable(cls):
    cls.__bases__ = (_JsonMixin,) + cls.__bases__
    return cls

@jsonable
class Data(typing.NamedTuple):
    name: str
    value: float
```

Do mind type checkers will not understand where the `.json()` come from.
Modifying the `__bases__` is preferable to creating a new class and inheriting from `cls`, and easily supports more methods unlike injecting the `.json()`.

If you don't wish to use a class decorator you can create a metaclass, but that's a bit more complicated. A metaclass won't work with the type checkers either.